# Implement stack's push method in a static array, but the program should also work if number of pushes > initial array size

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, stack

This is my first time doing Java as a part of college assignment where I have to implement Stack data structure, but the challenge is to make the code work for pushes greater than the initial array size. I am not allowed to work with ArrayList in this assignment. I can only use static array and resize when needed by copying contents to a new array and reassigning the old array as new array.

I try to achieve this using if condition which determines if the counter (which initially is 0, increases as the number of push increases) is greater than the initially defined size of the array.

Then I created a new method called stackextender where I put exceeding values in a new array called extensionstack. Then on a method mystackmodifier, I create a temparray and put contents of original stack and extensionstack in the temparray. At last i do mystack = temparray to copy the contents to my original stack. I think the code is having problem in this function (mystackmodifier),where I am modifying the contents of initial stack. The code is posted below:

```
public class StackOperations{
    int mystack[];
    int global_size;
    int counter = 0;
    int newcounter = 0;
    int extensionstack[] = new int[counter*2];

    public StackOperations(int size){
        this.mystack = new int[size]; //create a stack of size as mentioned while creating object
        this.global_size = size; //update the global variable 
    }
    //the below method will allow us to calculate the number of 

    public void push(int value){
        if (counter<global_size){
        mystack[counter] = value;
        counter += 1;//we have to do this unless counter < stacksize
        }
        else{
            /*so if I have to make my code work for user input greater than my initial stack size, 
            I am creating a new method called stackextender where I put new value in a new array called 
            extension stack. Then on the method, mystackmodifier I create a temparray and put contents of
            original stack and extensionstack in the temparray. At last i do mystack = temparray to 
            copy the contents to my original stack*/

            stackextender(value);
            counter ++;

        }


    }
    //This method puts exceeding values to a new stack called extension stack
    public void stackextender(int value){
        extensionstack[newcounter] = value;
        newcounter ++;
        }
    //This method modifies the contents of original stack 
    public void mystackmodifier(){
        int temparray[] = new int[(global_size+newcounter)*2];

        if(extensionstack.length>0){
            int key;
            for ( key = 0; key<mystack.length; key++){
                temparray[key] = mystack[key];
            }
        for (int i = 0; i<newcounter; i++){
            temparray[key+i] = extensionstack[i];
            }
        mystack = temparray;
        }

    }
```

Below is my main method

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayStack{
public static void main(String args[]){
    StackOperations mystack = new StackOperations(100);
    System.out.println(mystack.toString());
    /*Although the stack size is instantiated as 10, the code works for insertion for as many 
    number of items as demonstrated below*/
    for (int i = 0; i<150; i+=1){
        mystack.push(i);
    }

    int stacksize = mystack.getSize();
    if (stacksize == 0) {
        try{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }catch (NoSuchElementException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(mystack.toString());

}
```

Any help will be highly appereciated

Comment: Well, one problem is that `extensionstack` is initialized to be an empty array.

Comment: Yes, that is what i wanted to do. I wanted to put contents of exceeding pushes in `extensionstack` which I try to combine to a new array- temparray in `mystackmodifier` method. Then I reassign `mystack` to `temparray`

Comment: Well, you initialize that array to 0 length here - `int extensionstack[] = new int[counter*2];`, since counter is 0 at this point. You should initialize it in the constructor instead.

Comment: Okay, I did it. I also have a toString method and all other methods which I didn't post here. Now I am getting indexoutofbound exception in toString method. Can you take a look. [link](https://gist.github.com/shreezan123/369b454f6738eda2930359170147618e)

Comment: Why do you need a separate stackextender class? Why not just extend the array inside of push() when needed?